# Field Concatenation RDLC-Tablix

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have a rdlc report. I wish to display 2-fields together in 1-column of Tablix. The below expression works good when there is value. But also it shows #Error when there is no value..So how to avoid this #Error message..

Note : I wish to avoid only #Error message and I don't want to hide.

Thanks

```
=Fields!item_disc_perc.Value.ToString & vbcrlf & Fields!itm_dsc_val.Value.ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is "no value" as you say, does the Value property evaluate to "Nothing" (in VB) or null (C#)? If so, you will get a NullReferenceException. If it was in C#, I would recommend using the ?: operator. For example, replace:

```
=Fields!item_disc_perc.Value.ToString()
```

with

```
=Fields!item_disc_perc.Value != null ? Fields!item_disc_perc.Value.ToString() : "(null)"
```